# Box2d + CoCos2d: Moving an Object automatically to simulate computer movement in a game

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am working on a hockey game and I am implementing Single Player mode. I am trying to move the "computer's" paddle in offense mode (move towards the ball). I am using CoCos2d and Box2d. I am moving the paddle using MouseJoints. The problem is the Paddle doesnt move at all!

tick is called in init method

```
[self schedule:@selector(tick:)];
```

...

```
  - (void)tick:(ccTime) dt 
 {
  _world->Step(dt, 10, 10);    

  CCSprite *computer_paddle;
  CCSprite *ball;
  b2Body *computer_paddle_b2Body;
  float32 direction;
  b2Vec2 velocity;


  for(b2Body *b = _world->GetBodyList(); b; b=b->GetNext()) {    
   if (b->GetUserData() != NULL) {
    CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)b->GetUserData();      

    if (sprite.tag == 1) { //ball
     ball = sprite;
     static int maxSpeed = 10;
      velocity = b->GetLinearVelocity();
     float32 speed = velocity.Length();
      direction = velocity.y;

     if (speed > maxSpeed) {     
      b->SetLinearDamping(0.5);
     } else if (speed < maxSpeed) {
      b->SetLinearDamping(0.0);
     }

    } 

    if (sprite.tag == 3){ // paddle
     computer_paddle  = sprite;
     computer_paddle_b2Body = b; 


    }


  // update sprite position
  sprite.position = ccp(b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO,b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO);
  sprite.rotation = -1 * CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(b->GetAngle()); 


  } 


 }


 // update the computer paddle in single player moving it towards the ball using MouseJoint


 //move towards the ball
 b2Vec2 b2Position = b2Vec2(ball.position.x/PTM_RATIO,ball.position.y/PTM_RATIO);

 b2MouseJointDef md1;


md1.bodyA = _groundBody;

md1.bodyB = computer_paddle_b2Body;

md1.target = b2Position;

md1.collideConnected = true;

md1.maxForce = 9999.0 * computer_paddle_b2Body->GetMass();

_mouseJoint = (b2MouseJoint *)_world->CreateJoint(&md1);

computer_paddle_b2Body->SetAwake(true);
```

Comment: I would have attempted an answer, but your code is really hard to read.  You should follow the method and variable naming conventions of whatever language you are using.  Also, there's a way to paste code into a question so that it gets formatted properly.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether:

**a)** the body is sleeping

**b)** the body is a static body

If it is sleeping and you have no other bodies, disable sleeping entirely. Otherwise disable sleeping of the body: body->SetSleepingAllowed(NO)

Note: this is according to [Box2D 2.2.1 API Reference](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/Box2D/html/classb2_body.html) which isn't the default in cocos2d 1.0 yet, so the function may be different in your Box2D version.

Also check that your body is dynamic by looking up the b2BodyDef's type member and, if necessary, set it to be dynamic (see the b2BodyType enumeration). I'm not sure what the default is, it should be dynamic but this may depend on the Box2D version.